# Manual partitioning to install Ubuntu - Won't start

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.2 on my desktop computer on a separate hard drive which I bought for this sole purpose. The first hard drive contains windows 10. In order to do so, I formatted the disk via the Ubuntu installer which I have loaded on an USB stick. I followed the following guide (including the optional boot-partition step, I also tried the optional var and tmp-partition): https://askubuntu.com/a/343352

More specifically, these are the exact options I chose:

Options at the beginning:
[image]

Swap partition:
[image]

Root:
[image]

Home:
[image]

Everything together + bootloader:
[image]

Perhaps I should mention that at the beginning of everything, when I start the Ubuntu installer from the disk (so before all of these options), I get the following screen briefly before the Ubuntu installer loads:

[image]

After installing, when I start up the computer I reach the grub menu. I launch Ubuntu from there, which takes me to a very dark purple screen with nothing on it. After some time, my monitor switches to screen saver. Nothing happens then.

My hardware specs are the following:

- Samsung SSD 960 EVO M2
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti
- AMD Ryzen 7 1700
- 32 GB RAM
- ROG CROSSHAIR VI HERO Mainboard

Can someone help me?

Comment: Try to [install the nvidia drivers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia), there seems to be a problem with the `nouveau` kernel module.

Comment: A very good answer concerning the nvidia drivers can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/61433/507051).

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Im physically away from the computer and will try out the suggestions once Im back

Comment: @dessert: That's not helpful if OP can't even boot to a prompt.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/111298/497359

Comment: I was able to fix it with the link dessert and Severus Tux provided. The NVIDIA drivers were not installed. Thanks all for the help